# Как правильно писать экспорт шаблона в cpp-файле?

Tags: c++

Прошу помочь правильно экспортировать шаблон из файла реализации. Проект пишу с применением MSVS 2013.

У меня есть два типа, относительно которых пишутся специализации:

```
struct arch32 {};
struct arch64 {};
```

И есть конструктор, который расположен в hpp-файле:

```
namespace PE {
namespace Section {    
    class Detail
    {
    public:    
        template<typename Arch>
        Detail(const ImgSectionHeader& header, const Image<Arch>& image);
        double   entropy() const;
```

Пытаюсь написать экспорт таким образом:

```
template  Detail::Detail(const ImgSectionHeader& header, const Image<arch32>& image);
template  Detail::Detail(const ImgSectionHeader& header, const Image<arch64>& image);
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
implementation.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: double __thiscall PE::Section::Detail::entropy(void)const " (?entropy@Detail@Section@PE@@QBENXZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall readpe::OutputFormatter<struct PE::arch32>::formatSectionsDetails(void)" (?formatSectionsDetails@?$OutputFormatter@Uarch32@PE@@@readpe@@AAEXXZ)
```

Другими словами, экспорт шаблона написан неверно. Пытаюсь добавить arch32, arch64:

```
template  Detail::Detail<arch32>(const ImgSectionHeader& header, const Image<arch32>& image);
template  Detail::Detail<arch64>(const ImgSectionHeader& header, const Image<arch64>& image);
```

Но теперь другая ошибка, связанная с синтаксисом:

```
c:\projects\cpp-workspace\readpe\src\pe\implementation\section\section.hpp(114): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
c:\projects\cpp-workspace\readpe\src\pe\implementation\section\section.hpp(114): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
c:\projects\cpp-workspace\readpe\src\pe\implementation\section\section.hpp(115): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
c:\projects\cpp-workspace\readpe\src\pe\implementation\section\section.hpp(115): error C2059: syntax error : '<'
```

Спасибо @Vlad : Под "Экспорт шаблонов" понимаю сделать доступной реализацию шаблона из одной единицы трансляции в другой другой единице трансляции. Такое возникает когда декларация шаблона в h-файла, а реализация в cpp-файле. Но согласно статье [C++11 — removed and deprecated](https://habrahabr.ru/post/131512/) "экспорт шаблонов" в C++11 убрали

Comment: Ээээ... Что означает «экспортировать шаблон»? Почему весь шаблон не в header'е, как принято?

Comment: Потому что у меня шаблон с кодом, а не только из одних данных. И мне бы не хотелось часто изменяемые куски кода выносить в хедер.

Comment: Ну, это не позволит вам инстанциировать шаблон с другими типами. Если вам нужно всего два типа, нужен ли вам шаблон вообще?

Comment: Да, нужен. У меня есть почта в профиле и мы можем обсудить. Могу показать BitBucket репозиторий. Просто не хочется уходить от тематики ресурса вопрос-ответ, а обсуждение надо или нет может привести как раз уходу

Comment: Ну, нужен так нужен. Я сторонник того, чтобы писать шаблоны в header'е, вот и переспросил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось проще. Я забыл реализовать `entropy` метод. Каюсь. Компилятор меня даже носом ткнул в место ошибкой с `unresolved`-сообщением.

Рабочий вариант:

```
template  Detail::Detail(const ImgSectionHeader& header, const Image<arch32>& image);
template  Detail::Detail(const ImgSectionHeader& header, const Image<arch64>& image);
```